# pwm frequency to digital hi low

Tags: pwm

There  are two  type pwm signals, one pwm with 2.5khz 50% duty, second type 5khz 50% duty.  I am looking  solution  how to detect   2.5khz  as digital 1 and 5khz as 0, or  2.5khz-0, 5khz-1.   The signal will be detect using arduino, but I don't want to use pulsein  or other solution which detect length of signal.

*incorrect sample deleted*

[image: sample1][image: sample2]

Comment: Your description DOES NOT match your picture. It looks like 75% duty followed by 25% duty.

Comment: The new picture looks more in line with the text.

Comment: Yes, removed,  added real  samples

Comment: So does it need to be realized in hardware or what exactly does it mean you don't wanna use a solution which detects signal length?

Comment: yes , only hardware.

Comment: Looks like a 7474 and 74121 to me. Set up the '121 to go LO for 150 ms starting at rising edge of source. '121 output to '74 clk. Feed D of '74 from your source. Use '74 output.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is not PWM, it's [BFSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying).

It can be solved with an edge interrupt: Count the number of rising or falling edges in a timeframe. The number you get will tell you whether it's a 0 or a 1.

If you want a hardware-only solution, you could build an analog low-pass filter that suppresses everything above 2.5 kHz. If you get a signal you know it's the 2.5 kHz one (or DC), and if you don't, it's either the 5 kHz signal (or no signal). If you want to distinguish between 5 kHz and no signal, you need to build two filters.

There are probably many more ways to skin this cat, but there you have two of them.

Comment: It is PWM but with variable duty cycle if the diagram is to be believed.

Comment: You're right. I went by the textual description, but the illustration clearly doesn't match it.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach:
Load a capacitor via the high level of your input signal, and let it discharge via another resistor.

Choose the values for R1, R2 and C1 appropriately. Then for frequency above a certain threshold, the input signal of your controller will always see "1" and below it will see an alternating signal, which can be detected by using an interrupt input. It might be difficult to match the designed threshold to the input characteristics of your MCU inputs due to the "little" difference between the two frequencies. If that's the case you can add a comparator to make sure you have a proper discrimination between both signals.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXLVgA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>